# Simple flash as3 beginner programming

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am very new to flash and am wondering why the following code won't work everything seems to be in place to me but I'm sure theres something obvious missing. Any help would be appreciated

```
var rightPressed:Boolean = false;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);

function keyDownHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT);
rightPressed = true;
}     
 if(rightPressed){  
  trace("right");
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do and what do you mean "won't work" ?

Comment: For starters: indent your code properly. There are some obvious problems with your code if you attempt to indent it properly.

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove that `;` at the end of the line `if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT);` or change it to a bracket.

It's causing your code to always set `rightPressed = true;` because it's not under the conditional test.

And you missed a bracket at the end of the function.

I didn't test this suggestion, but with this it would look like this:

```
var rightPressed:Boolean = false;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);

function keyDownHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
 if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
   rightPressed = true;
 }     
 if(rightPressed){  
   trace("right");
 }
}
```

or just do your code inside the conditional test:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);

function keyDownHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
 if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
   trace("right");
 }     
}
```

Hope that helps ;)

Comment: Yes that helps a lot as you can tell I am a newb thank you!